# Re-export types so that they are no longer under a namespace

Tags: typescript, namespaces

I have an auto-generated Typescript file `types.d.ts` which is structured as follows:

```
declare namespace Definitions {
  export interface Foo { ... }
  export interface Bar { ... }
}
```

Since this file is generated, I do not want to edit it. Unfortunately, the generator tool creates these namespaces and it’s not in my control.

My end goal is to be able to use the interfaces `Foo` and `Bar` without having to use the `Definitions` namespace prefix.  At the moment, in another package that imports the one with the definitions, I can do

```
import { Definitions } from 'my-package-with-the-defs'

const foo: Definitions.Foo = { ... }
```

But what I would like is

```
import { Foo } from 'my-package-with-the-defs'

const foo: Foo = { ... }
```

---

I know I can re-export things from `my-package-with-the-defs`, eg by

```
import { Definitions } from './types'
export type Foo = Definitions.Foo
```

in some main (`index.ts`) file and that way I can use `Foo` as I wish. But the `Definitions` namespace contains several interfaces and I would want to re-export all of them into the ‘global’ namespace.

Is there a way to do this without either adding every single re-export individually or auto-generating this re-exporting file as well?

Comment: In short: **no**. Your best option is to (1) submit a PR to change the exported types upstream, or (2) to [use the compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) to identify the desired namespaced types and re-export them programmatically.

Comment: Would you like to see that as an answer, or am I still missing something?

Comment: I don’t think so. Yes, please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the (sad but true) solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without either adding every single re-export individually or auto-generating this re-exporting file as well?

Currently, no. Alternative options include:

1. Submitting a PR to change the exported types upstream
2. [Using the compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) to identify the desired namespaced types and re-export them programmatically